# Packaging node-webkit application as ".appx" (for Windows 8 Store)

Tags: windows, node.js, windows-8, windows-store-apps, node-webkit

I want to know how I'd be able to package a node-webkit application as an **.appx** for the Windows 8 Store? I've been able to create an **.exe** of my application that works as long as it's in the same directory as its .dll's.

Here's how my directory currently looks:

```
application/
    MyApplication.exe
    ffmpegsumo.dll
    icudt.dll
    libEGL.dll
    libGLESv2.dll
    nw.pak
```

I'm unfamiliar with Windows development since I primarily use OSX, so I'm not sure what steps to take next to package this .exe as a .appx. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I'm not particularly familiar with node-webkit but I'd assume that it doesn't result in a Windows Store App. The .appx format is only available for this type of apps which needs to correspond to certain kinds of behaviours (activation & launch protocols, API restrictions due to sandboxing etc.)

Comment: I can easily create an .exe of my node-webkit application that runs on Windows. From what I've read you can package any old .exe into a Windows 8 .appx file (since it's based on the zip format or something.)

Comment: Sure, it's just a zip file but that doesn't make it compatible to the Windows 8 Store App format. Store Apps are a special kind of application that requires a different architecture from a regular .exe file. A store app's lifecycle is managed completely different from a regular .exe as it can be activated in a couple of different ways (regular startup, search or share charm...) and will need to respond to suspend/resume events and then there's also a number of restrictions on available API to consider.

Answer (score 0):

I had worked with node-web-kit once, and I remember that your node app should have `index.html` file. `WinRt` apps are supporting `Html5/Js`. Try create `WinJs` app, put all files from `nw.pak` into project directories(`html/css/js`) and add your  extended library like references to your project. I'm not sure about adding extend libraries, winJs app can give an error.